# Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ProcessorInformation class missing in cimv2 namespace

Tags: wmi

**I need to perform a wmi query** on `Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ProcessorInformation` class from `cimv2` namespace to get `percentprocessortime`.

I could not find the class on windows server 2008.

I found it under `cimv2` on `2008R2` onwards.

How do I get this class on 2008 server?

WMIDIAG does not seem to give any information on this class.

Answer (score 2):

It's a Windows Server 2008 R2 class. It doesn't exist on Windows Server 2008, as you've discovered.

There's a LoadPercentage on the Win32_Processor class in Windows Server 2008 though. It might have what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

is the namespace right?
it should be `root/CIMV2`

and this for WMI Query `SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_ProcessorInformation`

if you still didn't found it, you maybe want to try this

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572

It contains list and example code of WMI's provided on your computer